# Read in / get encoding type of XML

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, deserialization, streamreader

Is there a possibility to read in the first line of an XML file separately? I have to get the information which encoding is used. The XMLs in my working folder have different encodings and depending on that I have to use the corresponding "Encoding.GetEncoding" for the deserialization method.

That's part of my code:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Document));
// read the XML document 
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

var encoding_windows = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
var encoding_utf = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
var sr = new StreamReader(current_file, encoding_windows, true);
var reader = XmlReader.Create(sr);
// restore the object's state using the deserialize method
var i = (Document)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Comment: The XmlReader so not need the first line.  So you can skip first line in your code using sr.ReadLine();  Add this line before you Create the XmlReader.

Answer (score 0):

you can use normal file read

```
using System.Linq;   

string line1 = File.ReadLines("MyFile.xml").First()
```

and use that `line1` from XML to do your actions